# How to open C# Solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am relatively new to programming and only have some experience with Python and MATLAB but was given an assignment in which I have to run and test a sample program using .NET. I'm set up with Windows 7 via VMWare running on my Macbook Pro and obviously I've got Visual Studio on the desktop.

I have a zip file of the sample program but am having trouble opening it correctly in Visual Studio. Inside the file there is a Microsoft Visual Studio Solution with the same name as the test program. When I open that I get error messages saying certain file paths are not found (which I assume means that I'm not opening the program correctly).

There are also:

- a couple XML configuration files
- a Visual C# Project File
- Visual C# Source files
- other folders entitled 'bin', 'obj', 'Properties'

Again, I know this might be a very rudimentary solution but I have been struggling with it for a few days and was hoping I might be able to find a solution here. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Unzip the zip to a known folder. Open Visual Studio -> click File -> Open -> Project/Solution and browse in the folder for the `.sln` file. Should be in the top-level folder.

Comment: Sounds like you exported the file from a location. Check the .sln-file for any absolute paths and change them to the corresponding location of where the files are in.

Comment: Sound like you're trying to open the solution file directly from within the Zip.
If this is the case, extract the contents, and it should work

Comment: in order to understand C#, you can create few programs. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Comment: If you tell us what the error message is you're getting we may be able to help further.

Answer (score 3):

If you have extracted it correctly, by double clicking on .sln file should launch the application on visual studio.

Comment: Hey Yagnesh, Thanks for the tip. When I double click the .sln file it gives the following error in visual studio:  C:\Users\Russell Johnson\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp4_Log4netSample.zip\Log4netSample\Log4netSample\Log4netSample.csproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Russell Johnson\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp4_Log4netSample.zip\Log4netSample\Log4netSample\Log4netSample.csproj'.  C:\Users\Russell Johnson\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp4_Log4netSample.zip\Log4netSample\Log4netSample\Log4netSample.csproj

Comment: Did you unzip the file before double clicking .sln file?

Comment: The error simply means the listed files are missing which could be lost when you unzipped the file. You need to check your zip while and the unzip version if unzip version has all the files from zipped file.

Comment: You're right! I didn't unzip it correctly. Working now. Thank you for the help

Comment: If this has helped you then can you please mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new solution and import files and references.